# Can't set div's content with Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

```
$('#messages').html('<p>Test</p>');

<div id="messages" style="height:520px; list-style: none; border: 1px solid black;" ></div>
```

For some reason this JQuery isn't working. Why?

Comment: Its working for me... and also here: http://jsfiddle.net/ukfsV/ do you have any more code than that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should work, providing of course that you have a proper link to the jquery library, of course. -Check the path)

Comment: That was it. Was fiddling around with the path for a while and swore it wasn't that but it was =/

Answer (score 1):

yep, all of above.
By the way: are you aware of this syntax:

```
$('<p>')
    .text('test')
    .addClass('ui-paragraph')
    .appendTo('#messages');
```

i find it more precise & powerful than the html method in some cases..

Answer (score 0):

This does look like valid code, especially when checking out Marks Fiddle.

Although the major difference between the fiddle and your code is the absensce of

```
$(function() { //script here });
```

or something like it.

I also imagine the the jquery is either external or inserted between  tags.

I tend to do two things 1. keep my scripts at the end of the page and wrap $(function() { //script here }); around my code. This maybe the problem here. It if the script is executed before the page loads their is no #message to append to.